How to add OpenStreetMap layer as bottom layer via QGIS processing script
I want to add an OpenStreetMap layer as the bottom layer of my project via a script. This works from the console:
project = QgsProject.instance()
root = project.layerTreeRoot()
all_layers = root.children()
count = len(all_layers)

osm_exists = any(l.name() == "OpenStreetMap" for l in all_layers)

if not osm_exists:
    urlWithParams = "type=xyz&url=http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png&zmax=19&zmin=0&crs=EPSG3857"
    rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, "OpenStreetMap", "wms")

    if rlayer.isValid():
        root.insertLayer(count, rlayer)

It seems that the easiest way to have this script be always available when a new project is created on the fly is using a Processing script. So I have converted this code to:
class MySetup(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        urlWithParams = "type=xyz&url=https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png&zmax=19&zmin=0&crs=EPSG:3857"
        layer_name = "OpenStreetMap"
        osm_layer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, layer_name, "wms")

        project = context.project()
        existing_layers = project.layerTreeRoot().children()
        store = context.temporaryLayerStore()

        osm_exists = any(l.name() == layer_name for l in existing_layers)

        if not osm_exists:
            if osm_layer.isValid():
                store.addMapLayer(osm_layer)
                context.addLayerToLoadOnCompletion(
                    osm_layer.id(),
                    QgsProcessingContext.LayerDetails(
                        layer_name, context.project(), "LAYER"
                    ),
                )

            else:
                print("error summary:", osm_layer.error().summary())


        return {}

But, of course, this adds the layer at the top, above any existing layers. How can I get the layer to appear at the bottom? Do I need to use a QgsProcessingLayerPostProcessorInterface? It seems extremely complicated and verbose for such a simple use case…
Alternatively, perhaps I should be calling the script another way. It doesn't have to be a Processing Script, I just want a simple way to run the script, ideally with a keyboard shortcut or from a menu item that I can assign a hotkey to.

You can try not adding your layer as bottom, but to move it after adding.
from qgis.utils import iface

#your_layer = iface.activeLayer()

ltv = iface.layerTreeView()

ltv.setCurrentLayer(your_layer)
ltv.defaultActions().moveOutOfGroup()

ltv.setCurrentLayer(your_layer)
ltv.defaultActions().moveToBottom()

replace "your_layer" on your layer variable or uncomment 2nd line if your layer selects after adding.

Thanks for the suggestion. This doesn't work because the layer isn't in the layer tree yet in processAlgorithm. It's only been added to the queue via addLayerToLoadOnCompletion(). I have also tried putting the ltv.defaultActions().moveToBottom() call in postProcessAlgorithm, but the layer is still missing. Any other ideas?

Oh, sorry then, I haven't experience in using proccesing.  But, as you wrote in question, proccesing isn't necessary.  Maybe you can try call simple script from proccessing (by signal e.g.)?
